# Grab Any device name using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ios

I know how to grab an ip address and also the name of the computer but I can not figure out how to grab the actual name of a device like an Iphone, Ipad. What Can I do to grab these names. I have a website with a counter and I just want to see which devices are going to my site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually looking for is the *User Agent*.   This is the string each device has that lets you know what the device is, and what browser is being used.

## ASP.NET

The simplest way to get the user agent (using asp.net) is like this:

```
var userAgent = Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
```

Depending on how you code your site, that will determine what you do with the user agent...  ie store it in a database, etc.

For example, an iPhone 5 user agent might look like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A405 Safari/8536.25
```

And here's a sample iPad user agent string...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25
```

This URL here gives a long list of possible user agents...

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

## Google Analytics

Another option you might consider is using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).  You would paste the Javascript code they provide you on to your site, and each time a visitor comes, they will track things like browser, operating system, geography, etc.  It's a great tool to get an in-depth look at where your traffic is coming from.